# why is this error 'The argument type 'List<AddEventModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AddEventModel''?

Tags: flutter

This maybe a silly questain i'm a beginner so help me. It is showing argument type List and a model 'AddEventModel' i create for Hive can't be assigned to parameter type 'AddEventModel' it is a valueNotifier.

[image: my code and error here]

Comment: Instead of .add, use .addAll

Comment: Please do not use screenshot or photo instead copy and paste the entire code so that it will be easy to debug for others.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use this for loop to add all events to the events notifier

```
for(var event in allEvents){
    eventsNotifier.value.add(event);
}
```

Comment: oh I didn't even think of for loop thanks for helping me out.